# multiple spark jobs writing to same hive partitioned external table - spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have Hive external table `MyTable` with `partition(load_date:String, load_type:String)` stored as parquet.  Function 
`loadData(start,end)` is a wrapper function that has a spark action `df.insertinto()` at the end. Calling this function with input as `loadData(20190101,20190103)` will create below HDFS directory structure

```
load_date=2019101/type=A
load_date=2019101/type=B
load_date=2019102/type=A
load_date=2019102/type=B
load_date=2019103/type=A
load_date=2019103/type=B


def loadData(start,end):
       .... 
       // dynamic insert for start to end date range
       df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto(MyTable) // for type A
       ....
       df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto(MyTable) // for Type B
```

Note - The 2 `insertinto()` in above function run sequentially for some reason.
Inside a single spark application I spin multiple spark jobs that write into `Mytable` but each job writes into a separate partition, something like -

```
val interval= [ (20190101,20190105), (20190106,20190110), (20190111,20190115), .....]

interval.grouped(3).foreach(grp => grp.par.foreach(slot => loadData(slot._1,slot._2))
```

3 jobs are triggered in parallel as expected, and the application successfully completes. But at the output HDFS location I see some random partitions missing.

For example, `type=B` partitions are missing inside `load_date=201910101` to `20190105`

```
load_date=20190101/type=A
load_date=20190102/type=A
load_date=20190103/type=A
load_date=20190104/type=A
load_date=20190105/type=A
load_date=20190106/type=A
load_date=20190107/type=A
load_date=20190108/type=A
load_date=20190109/type=A
load_date=201901010/type=A
load_date=20190106/type=B
load_date=20190107/type=B
load_date=20190108/type=B
load_date=20190109/type=B
load_date=201901010/type=B
```

Comment: Please check between 201910101 to 20190105,  the df is actually having records for type=B.

Comment: Yes it has, there no missing data issue here.  If I just run a single job instead of running parallel, I'm getting all partitions as expected.

Comment: is it consistent every time, you are loosing 201910101 to 20190105 ? try troubleshooting running the job only for the dates 20190101 to 20190105, and  then 20190106 to 20190110 ? you may get some clue.

Comment: No, its Random. Sometimes I get all partitions for  201910101 to 20190105 ,  but then missing partitions for other intervals. I'm running 3 jobs at a time , interval.grouped(3).foreach ... . Passing  20190101 to 20190105 will trigger only one job so that should run without any issues I guess. My interval variable becomes like this --- val interval= [ (20190101,20190105)]

Comment: overwrite will overwrite all partition in that directory, i.e whatever is written last that partition data will be available in hdfs .. what version of spark are you using ??

Comment: can you add complete if possible ??

Comment: @Srinivas : the table is a partitioned table - so df.insertinto(MyTable) would work as "Insert overwrite table MyTable partition(load_date,load_type )  select ......"
Spark kversion 2.3